# Ruby OptionParser: process all not specified options

Tags: ruby, command-line, optionparser

I am trying to a custom processor of all options not specified in `OptionParser`.
But `parse` raises exception when first unknown option is found.

Is it possible to get all unprocessed parameters and process them manually?

Comment: Kind of defeats the purpose of having `OptionParser`, no?

Comment: Don't think so. I expect tools to be flexible to extend them with plain ruby in any direction.

Comment: Well, ruby classes are open. Extend away, in any direction! :)